# Debugging code in R Markdown

Tags: r, debugging, r-markdown

I've been playing a little bit with R Markdown and I really like it, because after each of my analyses I need to write a (Word) report detailing the results. With R Markdown, the code and report are the same document, so it's easy to remember that I chose to perform analysis B at a certain point in the code, because of the results of analysis A before.

However, I'm not able to set breakpoints in R Markdown inside R Studio, and this limits severely the possibility of performing efficient debugging. This implies that in the end I can only use Markdown for very trivial analyses, where the R code is so simple that either I don't have to debug it, or I can debug it manually. It this to be expected, i.e., is it well-known that R Markdown can only be used for simple analyses? Or is there a solution?

Comment: I don't get the reason for the downvote. The question is clear: I cannot set breakpoints in R Markdown (or at least I'm not able to) using R Studio. So how do I debug complex code in R Markdown?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `browser()` in your code to set breakpoints. See https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205612627-Debugging-with-RStudio#debugging-in-r-markdown-documents

I've find it more useful to write custom functions in a .R and `source()` it in Markdown. Then, you get the best of both worlds.

Comment: In R Markdown I usually have many chunks. Are you suggesting to write one custom function for each chunk? If the result of one function depends on a function in another chunk, it seems that debugging would get complicated.

Comment: No, I usually write all the functions I'm using in a few .R files (e.g., one for common custom functions I reuse in many analyses, and one for custom functions I wrote for this particular analysis), source the files in the first chunk, and use the functions in subsequent chunks.

Comment: While I support the validity of this answer - i.e. "don't shoot the messenger" - this `RMarkdown` is inferior to a `jupytext` / `jupyter` approach in which the _same_ file can either be debugged as a fully- baked self-contained script or drive a notebook interaction.   I prefer the `R` language but `RMarkdown` is going to be awkward

Answer (score 1):

You can generate Word and other reports from normal R scripts using `knitr::spin` in combination with special roxygen2-style comments. Then you can run your script and use breakpoints as normal.

https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/articles_report_from_r_script.html

There's also a toolbar button in RStudio to do this.

Comment: Indeed. This makes debugging easier. I'd say for R code heavy reports I'd prefer using .R files with special comments, and for text heavy reports I'd use .Rmd